# Django-Rest MultiPartParser vs JsonParser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios

Imagin in javscript have a object like below :

`{is_active:false,date:null}`

it is the data that i get from a form and then i POST this data to the django server

when i send data with header: 'Content-Type': 'application/json' , in server i receive this:

`is_active:False`

`date:None`

but when i send data with header: 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' , in server i receive this:

`is_active:'false'`

`date:'null'`

is there any way to when sending data with 'multipart/form-data' header , and geting python object insted of get an strings